# Precentage wise data distribution in K6

Tags: javascript, testing, performance-testing, load-testing, k6

Can I know how to distribute data by precentage wise in K6?

Like this example

[image: 1]

Can I know how to distribute data by precentage wise in K6 using .csv files?

Comment: Load all files, generate a random number between 0 and 100, then select from the matching file? Would that work? e.g. 42 would select set 1, 69 would select set 2, and 99 would select set 3. Not perfectly distributed, but should be close enough.

Answer (score 0):

I can think of two possible solutions to this problem:

1. Use [`--execution-segment`](https://k6.io/docs/using-k6/k6-options/reference/#execution-segment)
2. Implement a stochastic approach. Not perfect, but probably good enough™

##### Execution segments

k6 allows to partition your test run into segments. This requires to run multiple k6 instances in parallel.

```
import papaparse from 'https://jslib.k6.io/papaparse/5.1.1/index.js';
import { SharedArray } from 'k6/data';

const csvData = new SharedArray('csv', function () {
  return papaparse.parse(open(__ENV.datafile), { header: true }).data;
});

export default function () {
  // use csvData[...]
}
```

You have to start 3 tests in parallel (on different hosts or as background jobs) and specify the path to the data file for each:

```
$ k6 run -e datafile=data_set_01.csv --execution-segment '50%' loadtest.js &
$ k6 run -e datafile=data_set_02.csv --execution-segment '30%' loadtest.js &
$ k6 run -e datafile=data_set_03.csv --execution-segment '20%' loadtest.js &
```

References:

- https://k6.io/docs/examples/data-parameterization/#from-a-csv-file
- https://k6.io/docs/using-k6/k6-options/reference/#execution-segment
- https://k6.io/docs/using-k6/environment-variables/

##### Random sampling

Load all 3 files into memory, then use a random variable to select which file to read from. You will not get perfect distribution, but only need to start a single k6 process.

```
import papaparse from 'https://jslib.k6.io/papaparse/5.1.1/index.js';
import { SharedArray } from 'k6/data';

const csvData = new SharedArray('csv', function () {
  return [
    'data_set_01.csv',
    'data_set_02.csv',
    'data_set_03.csv',
  ].map(file => papaparse.parse(open(file), { header: true }).data);
});

function rnd() {
  const x = Math.random();
  if (x < 0.5) return 0;
  if (x < 0.8) return 1;
  return 2;
}

function selectRandomCsv() {
  return csvData[rnd()];
}

export default function () {
  // use selectRandomCsv()[...]
}
```

Executing requires no extra care:

```
$ k6 run loadtest.js
```

References:

- https://k6.io/docs/examples/data-parameterization/#from-a-csv-file