# How can I run multiple functions in k6 simultaneously, with specified rate per function

Tags: javascript, benchmarking, k6

I'm trying to figure out a way to issue two separate requests in k6, with each request limited in relation to the other.

For example, I have two POST requests created, I want one to be hit 90% of the test run and the other 10%, to simulate a more busy and less busy endpoints being hit by requests on the same HTTP server.

EDIT: The point of the exercise is not to generate a predictable load, but to generate a maximum (in terms of ops/sec) load the server can take and measure it. The different rates of request types are needed for the benchmark to simulate a realistic load.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [scenarios](https://k6.io/docs/using-k6/scenarios/) to call different test functions with different request rates by specifying a [constant arrival rate executor](https://k6.io/docs/using-k6/scenarios/executors/constant-arrival-rate/).

You have to pre-calculate the per-endpoint rates manually, but you could easily define a function to compute the correct rates from a total base rate.

```
const TOTAL_RPS = 100;
function rate(percentage) {
  return TOTAL_RPS * percentage;
}

export const options = {
  scenarios: {
    busy: {
      exec: 'busy_endpoint',
      executor: 'constant-arrival-rate',
      duration: '10m',
      preAllocatedVUs: 50,
      rate: rate(0.9) // 90%
    },
    lazy: {
      exec: 'less_busy_endpoint',
      executor: 'constant-arrival-rate',
      duration: '10m',
      preAllocatedVUs: 5,
      rate: rate(0.1), // // 10%
    }
  }
};

export function busy_endpoint() {
  // will be called 90 times per second (90% of 100 rps)
  http.get('http://example.com');
}

export function less_busy_endpoint() {
  // will be called 10 times per second (10% of 100 rps)
  http.get('http://example.com');
}
```

---

Depending on your requirements and the complexity of the logic, an alternative could be a stochastic approach: each time you enter the method, you generate a random number and based on the result take one or the other endpoint (or any logic for that matter).

What could that look like?

```
function busy_endpoint() {
  // will be called roughly for 90% of your requests
  http.get('http://example.com');
}

function less_busy_endpoint() {
  // will be called roughly for 10% of your requests
  http.get('http://example.com');
}

function get_endpoint() {
  const r = Math.random();
  if (r < 0.1) return less_busy_endpoint;
  return busy_endpoint;
}

export default function() {
  const endpoint = get_endpoint(); // gets busy with 90% chance and less_busy with 10% chance
  endpoint(); // calls the endpoint
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I already found that when multiple scenarios are defined they execute in parallel. Since I'm not really testing a web server but a database that has an HTTP endpoint, I'm basically trying to simulate a typical DB benchmark, something akin to cassandra-stress or YCSB. 

I created two scenarios, one that sends INSERTS via POST and one the sends SELECTs via POST. same duration, one with 90 vus and the other with 10 vus, with the executor set to 'constant-vus'. Can you confirm that achieves the 90%-10% rate between the two? Or should I switch to `constant-arrival-rate` and use `rate()`

Comment: @dyasny `constant-vus` executes "as fast as possible". If your endpoint/server is already saturated, some VUs will pause and wait for resources to become available. With `constant-arrival-rate`, more VUs will be added to keep the target rate. I recommend reading about [Open and closed models](https://k6.io/docs/using-k6/scenarios/concepts/open-vs-closed/). It sounds like you want the _open model_ (i.e. `constant-arrival-rate`)

Comment: My objective is to measure ops/sec, try and saturate the server to the max it can take

Comment: @dyasny ops/sec can be controlled via `constant-arrival-rate`. `constant-vus` doesn't directly relate to ops/sec, but is dependent on the latency of your endpoint. But you can try both approaches and then look at the metrics (k6 metrics and server side metrics) if the distribution is correct (i.e. expected).

Comment: Thanks, I'm not looking to control ops/sec, I'm looking to find out how much ops/sec I can squeeze out of my server. So I need k6 to push as much as it can, until I see faults or rising latencies

Comment: @dyasny `ramping-arrival-rate` allows to you increase the rate based on time. Anyways, use scenarios to define scenarios which apply a percentage of your target load, totalling your expected load. I will extend my answer later, there is another approach using randomness to distribute the load across your endpoints. (See https://stackoverflow.com/a/75379390/112968 for the stochastic approach and instead of switching the data file, switch the endpoint based on your random variable)

Comment: @dyasny I have extended the answer with a probabalistic solution.